# Android Login throws up JSON Error: No Value for Error

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I have been doing this simple Android project on Login and Registration. 
    This involves passing app key token through JSON in order to call the Login Service. Whenever I try to Login, it throws the error -> JSON Error: No Value for Error. Not able to resolve it! Can anyone help me out with this? The log shows: "Error 502 - Invalid App Key"

```
package cscs.sktk; 


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import webservices.utilities.AppConfig;
import webservices.utilities.AppController;
import webservices.utilities.WebServiceParamKeys;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnlogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;



@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lgnbutton);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);


    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn())
    {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String username = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (username.isEmpty())
            {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Username!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(password.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else
            {
                checkLogin(username, password);
            }

        }

    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging you in!");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, AppConfig.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);



                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject paramObj = new JSONObject();
            try
            {
                paramObj.put(WebServiceParamKeys.appKeyToken, "dummyappkey");
                paramObj.put(username, "username");
                paramObj.put(password, "password");

            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: please show json string which getting from server

Comment: @Saadat1992 please post your stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

From above code "error" seems to be String. So try getting it by using getString() method like below,

String error=jObj.getString("error");